# Add a space between string after multiplying the original ones

Tags: python

I have multiplied the original string and I want to add a space between them. How can I achieve it?

```
my_str = 'Data Science'
print(my_str * 3)
```

Output:

```
Data ScienceData ScienceData Science
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `join`

```
my_str = 'Data Science'
' '.join([my_str]*3)  # -> 'Data Science Data Science Data Science'
```

Comment: Hello Chris. Thanks so much for your help. How about having a string in this way. ```my_str=Data Science```,```my_dbl_str = my_str+my_str```. I have tried ''' ' '.join([my_dbl_str]*3)''' but it only returns ''' Data ScienceData Science Data ScienceData Science Data ScienceData Science '''

Comment: Make sure `my_dbl_str` is passed as a list to `join`

Comment: Thanks and it helps me out!

Answer (score 0):

Add a space to the end of your string like so:

```
my_str = 'Data Science'
print( (my_str + ' ') * 3)
```

This way, when the string is repeated, the space is automatically included with every repition.

Comment: While yes, this is a solution, it wouldn't work well if the string comes from client input (or similar). Additionally, this would create a trailing space which the OP may want to avoided (and require an extra step to remove)

Comment: Good suggestion, I've edited my response such that the variable is no longer modified. And I should add for completness, the trailing spaces can be dealt with by only multiplying 2 instances of the string and adding on the last instance `print( (my_str + ' ') * 2 + my_str)`